# Can we control iphone camera flash light intensity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

Can we control iphone camera flash light intensity? 
I am developing Iphone App for eye Retina and in that I required to control the light intensity (increase or decrease flash light ) but I am unable to find anything relevant I do not know  whether Apple allow this or not please help me in finding this solution. Thank you.

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch]) {
  [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
  [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
  [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

I am using this code to On flash light.
i have managed to resolve this by adding these lines of code.

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
    slider.minimumValue = 0.2f;
    [slider setContinuous:YES];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:slider];

    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(success)
        {
            [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
And then write this method somewhere in your code
- (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: Here is Your solution:- [Control iphone camera flash](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera)

Comment: i have managed to controll flash light for iphone camera through a slider and here is the code which helped me.

Comment: - (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

Comment: UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
    slider.minimumValue = 0.2f;
    [slider setContinuous:YES];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:slider];